# Run batch script with admin right on network directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, admin

On windows 7 I mount one network directory using "Right click on Computer" then "Connect a Network Drive". After this, I want to execute a batch script using admin rights. This script is on the Network Drive.

So I just right-click on the batch script and I click on "Execute width admin right" but CMD opens and close with no message. I think this is due to the that I have mounted the network drive without the admin rights but how can I do this?

NB: the script executes a few commands for installing a software that is on the network drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really mount a share with 'admin rights'.  Your user account has whatever rights are granted to it by the server admin.  If you need 'execute' permissions for the share then the admin will have to grant your account that right.  Alternately, you can mount the share using a different set of credentials that has the rights you need, which would have to be given to you by the admin.